# Scroll to position without smooth animation on GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to move instantly the GridView to a position (the beginning of the grid in my case). I tried the following:

```
this.gridView.scrollTo(0, 0);
this.gridView.setScrollX(0);
this.gridView.setScrollY(0);
this.gridView.scrollTo(0, this.gridView.getTop());
this.gridView.computeScroll();
// Doing the previous in a post operation
```

None of these work. The only workaround I have is:

```
this.gridView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(0, 0, 0);
```

This actually scrolls, but even if I gave a duration of 0, it still does a short scroll animation.

Comment: you can try this.gridView.setSelection(0) ;

Comment: Yes, it was actually the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your gridView has an id of grid. so if it dose not have just add this

```
android:id="@+id/grid"
```

to it, so in `onCreate` method call these functions:

```
GridView v = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid); 

v.requestFocus();
```

if the above trick dose not work, try put your `GridView` into `RelativeLayout` and do above trick for

`RelativeLayout`